# Assigning a task to a thread that is idle

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Here's a script that prints out 100 numbers using threads. The order doesn't matter; as long as 100 numbers are printed out. I would like to use 10 threads to do the job, each doing mutually exclusive tasks.

Following from the example provided at [ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Thread.html), I wrote this

```
$threads = []

def make_thread(id, num)
  t = Thread.new do
    sleep(60) if id == 0
    p num
  end
  $threads.push(t)
end

100.times do |i|
  make_thread(i % 10, i)
  if $threads.size > 10
    $threads.each {|t| t.join }
    $threads.clear
  end
end
```

However, one thread always takes a long time to complete. In this case, it sleeps for 60 seconds before it goes and finishes its task.

Because I'm iterating over each thread and calling `join`, Ruby will wait until all of the threads have finished their tasks before returning, as expected.

How would I change the code so that instead of waiting for all threads to complete before moving on, I assign a task to a thread if one is available and wait ONLY if no threads are available?

The current implementation simply creates a new thread everytime I want to run a task, but it may be nice to just hold on to an existing thread and just tell it to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small piece of code to illustrate how you can use a Queue to synchronize your threads in Ruby (I tried to keep it short):

```
require 'thread'

$pm = Mutex.new         # mutex to print on screen
$queue = Queue.new      # input queue
$oks = Queue.new        # output queue

10.times do |i|
  Thread.new(i) do |j|
    loop do
      m = $queue.pop
      $pm.synchronize { puts "pop#{j}! #{m}" }
      $oks.push('ok')
    end
  end
end

100.times { |i| $queue.push(i) }

sleep 1 while $oks.length < 100
```

Here I create 10 threads with an infinite loop, the key is that the `Queue` will make a thread block on `pop` until something is available, and you can have as many consumers as you want. The second `Queue` is just used as a counter in the example.

One thing to note is that the loop creating the tasks does not wait, so if the threads are very slow to process their data, you could end up with 90 items waiting in `$queue`. If it were too much, you could minimize the load by changing the loop to:

```
100.times do |i|
  sleep 1 while $queue.length > 10
  $queue.push(i)
end
```

I hope that that's enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, that was one of the approaches I was thinking of: having a pool of jobs that my main thread creates while a separate pool of job-running threads goes and runs any jobs that are currently available. I wasn't sure where to start with that idea so this helps a lot.